# Custom UIView delegate not detecting touchesBegan

Tags: objective-c, ios

I did my research but haven't found an answer to the following problem: I have a custom delegate –subclass of UIView– and for some reason touchesBegan isn't working in the delegate implementation.

**TestView.h**

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TestView;

@protocol TestViewDelegate <NSObject>
@end

@interface TestView : UIView
@property (assign) id <TestViewDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**TestView.m**

```c
#import "TestView.h"

@implementation TestView

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touch detected on TestViewDelegate");
}

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TestView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<TestViewDelegate>
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```c
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UILabel* title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 280, 40)];
[title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:30]];
[title setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[title setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[tile setText:@"Test"];
[self.view addSubview:title];    
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
}

@end
```

What am I missing to make sure `touchesBegan` from TestView.m gets called when touches occur in ViewController.m?

Comment: You missed the main part - you need to create and use TestView in order to make it correct

Comment: The implementation is wrong. Please check docs and examples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your last line indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of views and view controllers. Touches don't occur in view controllers; touches occur in views. After a view is touched, it tells its controller that it was touched, and the controller does something with this information. The way that it does this is through a pattern called delegation.

So let's go through this piece by piece. In order to get what you want, you would have to do the following:

First: create an instance of `TestView` and add it as a subview of the view controller's view.

Now the view exists, and when you tap it you will see your `"Touch detected on TestViewDelegate"` logged to the console. But it won't actually do anything with the delegate (there isn't even a delegate yet!).

Second: set the newly created `TestView`'s `delegate` property to the view controller. Do this after you create the `TestView` instance but before you add it to the view hierarchy.

Now they're hooked up a little, but the view is never talking to its delegate (this doesn't happen automatically; when you create a delegate protocol you have to specify what messages the view will be able to send it).

Third: add a method to the `TestViewDelegate` protocol and implement that method in the view controller. This could be something like `touchesBeganOnTestView:(TestView *)sender`, or whatever else you want the view to tell the delegate when it's touched. That looks like this:

```
@class TestView;
@protocol TestViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)touchesBeganOnTestView:(TestView *)sender;
@end
```

You have to add the `@class` line because the protocol declaration comes before the declaration of `TestView` -- at that point in the file, the compiler doesn't know what "`TestView`" means, so to avoid a warning you say "don't worry, I'm going to declare this later."

Fourth: invoke that method from `TestView`'s `touchesBegan`. This is as simple as adding the line `[self.delegate touchesBeganOnTestView:self];`.

That'll get you what you want. From your question I'm gathering that you're pretty new to iOS/Objective-C, and it's going to be difficult if you don't have a solid understanding of the fundamentals. A good place to start might be [Apple's description of delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation Ian, I really appreciate it. And you guessed it right, I'm new to iOS/Ocjectice-C :)

Comment: I am also learning this stuff for the first time. And this explanation was the best/clearest one I've seen. Thank you so much!